# How do I build a list from all selected cells of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hello all and thanks for your time.
I would like to know How I can build a list of all the cell data selected and write that into an array which I then write into a .plist

I just want to keep adding to the "*selecedArray" object from the selected cells.

When I "NSLog" my data the current code below shows that I over write the last selection therefore...  I end up with the last selected cell.  Hope that makes sense.

Thanks Ahab.

```
NSMutableArray *selectedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableDictionary *New_myData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
  NSString *selected = [prodArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [selectedArray addObject:selected];
  [New_myData setValue:selectedArray forKey:@"SelctedPrds"];

   NSLog( @"data from BuildString %@", New_myData);
```

Comment: If this code is executed every time a selection is made, you're recreating the `selectedArray` object each time, so its contents are always going to be just the most-recently selected object. Make `selectedArray` a property of the view controller instead if you want to hold onto the list of selected objects for longer.

Comment: @warrenm - Not sure how to execute your advice.  I will google "array as property of view controller" and see where that goes. Thx for the advice.

Comment: @gregheo gives good step-by-step instructions below. If you don't know what properties are, I recommend brushing up on Objective-C programming with Cocoa before you dive into iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method?

If so, you're creating a **new array** `NSMutableArray *selectedArray` every time the user selects a row, which means it will always have a single item (i.e. the row that was just selected).

You need an array in a higher scope. Try setting up `selectedArray` as an instance variable/property on the class. You'll need to initialize the array in the class's `init` method. Then when the user selects a row, add it to the array and it will hold onto its state properly.

You may also need to code to release the memory (if you're not using ARC) and perhaps some way to clear out the array (if there's a "clear" or "deselect all" kind of option in your app)

Comment: Thank You Very much !!!!!! As a beginner I was intimidated by the the phrase "instance variable/property on the class."  However the phrase "You need an array in a higher scope" saved the day !!! there was enough regular advice for me to piece together the intention.  Thank you Again works great. As for memory this is on ios5 on xcode 4.2 ....not sure what ARC is.  Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method to get the list of selected cells `tableView:indexPathsForSelectedRows` it will return you the array of all selected cells